# Expanded ExpandBar is cut off

Tags: java, swt

[image: Directly after this bar there are other controls]

I have a dialog that has two tabs. The tabs with the `ExpandBar` looks like this:

```
Composite page = createTabItem(
                tab,
                new GridLayout(5, false),
                Messages.Title,
                UITestId.PropertiesTab);
```

After that I have an `ExpandBar`:

```
ExpandBar bar = new ExpandBar(parent, SWT.NONE);
Composite selectionArea = new Composite(bar, SWT.NONE);
```

After adding some buttons and so on, I have this at the end:

```
ExpandItem item = new ExpandItem(bar, SWT.NONE, 0);
item.setText("Ausgabeformate auswählen");
item.setControl(selectionArea);
item.setHeight(selectionArea.computeSize(SWT.DEFAULT, SWT.DEFAULT).y);
```

How can I make the `ExpandBar` (if expanded) overlap the controls that are bellow it. Or if this does not work: How can I dynamically "push" the controls that are bellow the expanded `ExpandBar`away so I can see what is inside the `ExpandBar`.

Comment: You can call `layout(true, true)` on their parent.

Comment: Doesn't change anything. :(

Comment: Can you post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can have a go at your code?